# Cech Homology Differentials?

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, sheaf-cohomology

Is it possible for a differential in a Cech complex to be an isomorphism?
If so, would that imply that the homology at the object right before the differential is trivial?

I have a very weird open covering of that results in many objects in the Cech complex being isomorphic, so I am wondering if there is some error.

Comment: Maybe you could write down some of your own ideas so that we see how to help best.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chain complex and its homologies is a general algebraic construction. Once you have an isomorphism $C_i\stackrel{\partial_i}{\to} C_{i-1}$, then the $i$th homology $H_i$, being the kernel of $\partial_i$ divided by the image of $\partial_{i+1}$, is trivial (as the kernel is trivial).

By the way, the Čech complex associated to the empty covering of the empty set consists of a chain of trivial groups and all $\partial_i$ are isomorphisms. Surely, you can find many nontrivial cases as well.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the last sentence of the question.